# jQuery: shuffle objects within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, shuffle

I have taken the following object as an example:

```
var questions = {
   "1": {
       "question": "What animal goes 'woof'",
       "a": "Duck",
       "b": "Cat",
       "c": "Dog",
       "answer": "Dog"
   },
   "2": {
       "question": "What color is a giraffe",
       "a": "Yellow",
       "b": "Orane",
       "c": "Blue",
       "answer": "Yellow"
   },
   "3": {
       "question": "What is 2 + 2",
       "a": "6",
       "b": "4",
       "c": "9",
       "answer": "4"
   },
   "4": {
       "question": "What is 4 + 8",
       "a": "12",
       "b": "17",
       "c": "100",
       "answer": "12"
   },
   "5": {
       "question": "What is 4 - 1",
       "a": "5",
       "b": "91",
       "c": "3",
       "answer": "3"
   }
};
```

I would like to shuffle these questions in a particular way.

I would like to maintain the property name's and order (1,2,3 .etc.), but shuffle the values.

So the first property of 'questions' would still be "1" but the object containing the  "question", "a", "b", "c", "answer" would be shuffled.

Hopefully that make's sense, just ask if I've been unclear. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: An object has no order of its properties. Why don't you use an array?

Comment: Thanks pimvdb, your right. I was getting blinded by another issue and didn't stop to think about how silly this question was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I don't see the point in having the "1", "2", "3" properties at all, your array just needs to be an array of the question objects.  The one at the first index (0) is "1", the second index is "2".  This can be inferred by position.

```
var question = [{question 1 data}, {question 2 data}];
```

Once you've done that and simplified it, you can use a shuffle function like the one described [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/849).

Comment: Yep your right, for a reason too long winded to mention I thought I needed an object here. Stupidly, I had effectively created an array anyway. thanks

Comment: @DaveKingsnorth i second Moo-Juice's answer, only because i deal with Json feeds all the time. arrays just make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better data structure:

```
var questions = [
    { "question": "What animal goes 'woof'", "answers": ["Dog","Cat","Duck"] },
]
```

i.e. the first answer is always correct.

In your code, you can copy the first answer into a variable (so you know the correct answer) and then simply shuffle the `answers` array.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, your right that's probably a better format. I'm going to keep the current format and just make the questions object an array of objects instead (as always I'm pushed for time and would rather not rewrite parts of my script).